# keyUsage command not found (for create certificat in non interactive mode)

Tags: openssl, ssl, certificates

I would like to create a certificate files for my website.

In the past, I use a non interactive script for doing that and it work perfectly.

Now, I want to use again this script but it stop in this line :
`keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment`
with this error :

> ./scripts/generate-ssl-certificat.sh: line 16: keyUsage: command not found

I already install those packages in my Ubuntu 18 system :

- sudo apt-get install openssl ssl-cert
- sudo apt-get install ca-certificates -y

**What kind of packages do I need for executing keyUsage ?**

---

This is the automatic created certificate script which use

```
mkdir ~/certs
cd ~/certs

### Certificat Authority
openssl genrsa -des3 -out myCA.key 2048 # generate Certificat Authority key
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key myCA.key -sha256 -days 1825 -out myCA.pem # generate root certificat

### Certificat webSite
openssl genrsa -out compty-tmp.key 2048
openssl req -new -key compty-tmp.key -out compty-tmp.csr


### create compty-tmp.ext
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = compty-tmp

### create the certificate: using our CSR, the CA private key, the CA certificate, and the config file:
openssl x509 -req -in compty-tmp.csr -CA myCA.pem -CAkey myCA.key \
-CAcreateserial -out compty-tmp.crt -days 825 -sha256 -extfile compty-tmp.ext
```

Comment: Was the section from `### create compty-tmp.ext` to `### create the certificate:` intended to be written to a file (perhaps using a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document))? As it's written write now, the shell is trying to interpret it.

Comment: No because this script already run correctly in the past with other project and server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following section:

```
### create compty-tmp.ext
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = compty-tmp
```

is meant to be created in a separate file (`compty-tmp.ext`) which is passed to OpenSSL with the `-ext compty-tmp.ext` option in the last line.  The above section is not a script, but is in the OpenSSL config file format.

It just so happens that the first two lines have no space before the equals symbol, so your shell interpreted that as a variable assignment.  On the third line, there is a space before the equals (which is permitted in OpenSSL config files), so your shell didn't like it.

Therefore, cut the above section into a new file, leaving the following as your script:

```
mkdir ~/certs
cd ~/certs

### Certificat Authority
openssl genrsa -des3 -out myCA.key 2048 # generate Certificat Authority key
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key myCA.key -sha256 -days 1825 -out myCA.pem # generate root certificat

### Certificat webSite
openssl genrsa -out compty-tmp.key 2048
openssl req -new -key compty-tmp.key -out compty-tmp.csr

### create the certificate: using our CSR, the CA private key, the CA certificate, and the config file:
openssl x509 -req -in compty-tmp.csr -CA myCA.pem -CAkey myCA.key \
-CAcreateserial -out compty-tmp.crt -days 825 -sha256 -extfile compty-tmp.ext
```

Comment: Thank you for this great response ! I rewrite my script with any things of your advice and it work.